# Getting Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status on Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers

Getting Response to pre-flight request doesn't pass access control check:

It does not have HTTP ok status on Laravel API. Everything is working fine on localhost but when I am deploying on a live server getting the above error. My Cors.php code:

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
return $next($request)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',env('FRONTEND_URL'))
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-
Token-Auth, Authorization,x-xsrf-token,api-access-key');
}
```

Comment: Can you try on your server with Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* ?

Comment: No! it gives an CORS error that wildcard not allowed.

Comment: I already tried with *

Comment: ON Local Server everything is working as expected! Get error on Live server only.

Comment: For debugging purpose are you able to remove all other cors headers and only leave the * ?

Comment: Is the FRONTEND_URL environment variable correct on production?

Comment: Yes I cross checked FRONTEND_URL is correct!